# When is $ 0\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

For any two nonzero integers $m$ and $n$, we can construct an exact sequence
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to 0
$$
where the first map sends $k+n\mathbb{Z}\to mk+nm\mathbb{Z}$, and the second map sends $k+nm\mathbb{Z}\to k+m\mathbb{Z}$.

My hunch is that the sequence is split iff $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime. I want to find an isomorphic sequence
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to 0
$$
If $f:\mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is to be an isomorphism, necessarily $n$ and $m$ are coprime. I wanted to define an isomorphism by $f(1+nm\mathbb{Z})=(1+n\mathbb{Z},1+m\mathbb{Z})$. However, the diagram of sequences doesn't commute, because going around the first square along the top I get
$$
k+n\mathbb{Z}\to mk+nm\mathbb{Z}\to(mk+n\mathbb{Z},0+m\mathbb{Z})
$$
but going the other way the canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ into the direct sum gives
$$
k+n\mathbb{Z}\to k+n\mathbb{Z}\to (k+n\mathbb{Z},0+m\mathbb{Z}).$$

So the first coordinate is messing me up. Is my hunch wrong? Is there a more restrictive condition that $n$ and $m$ be coprime, but $n\mid m-1$ or something? I get this second condition by noticing $mk+n\mathbb{Z}=k+n\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n\mid (m-1)k$, and this must hold for all $k$, including $k=1$.

Comment: Have you tried the Splitting Lemma?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I'm aware of the splitting lemma. I'm using one of the equivalent statements. Is there a better condition to use?

Comment: No, you are basically figuring out the existence of a left-inverse for the map $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/nm \Bbb Z$.  Note that if $n$ divides $m-1$ then $n$ and $m$ are automatically coprime.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Thanks, but is that a necessary and sufficient condition for the sequence to be split? That's what I can't tell.

Comment: Well, the existence of such a left-inverse is equivalent to the sequence splitting, by the Splitting Lemma.

Comment: I know that they're equivalent by the Splitting Lemma. I'm curious about a condition on $n$ and $m$ that ensures the sequence is split.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem is your friend. If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then it promises you integers $a,b$ such that $a\equiv1\pmod n$ and $a\equiv0\pmod m$, and $b\equiv0\pmod m$ and $b\equiv1\pmod n$.

Comment: And if $\gcd(n,m)=d>1$ please count the number of solutions to $dx=0$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{mn}$ (resp. $\Bbb{Z}_{m}\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{n}$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Isn't then number of solutions to $dx\equiv 0\pmod{mn}$ just $\gcd(d,mn)=d$? Sorry, I don't see how either of those comments relate to my question. I'm just curious if a necessary and sufficient condition exists on $m$ and $n$ for the sequence to be split.

Comment: If $s:\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}/mn\Bbb{Z}$ is a splitting homomorphism, then $s(\overline{1})=\overline{x}$, where you need $x\equiv 1\pmod m$ for the composition $p\circ s$ to be identity of $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ ($p$ is the projection in you SES). You also need $x\equiv0\pmod n$ for $s$ to be well-defined.

Comment: And if you want to find a splitting homomorphism at the other end $s:\Bbb{Z}/mn\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, then...

Comment: The suggestion to count the number of solutions of $dx=0$ was to prove the necessity of $\gcd(m,n)=1$ for the sequence to split. You already seemed to know about that, sorry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. I'm not in any course actually, maybe I should remove the homological algebra tag. Just one thing, why do we need $x\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for $s$ to be well defined? Is it something like: if $k\equiv j\pmod{m}$, then $s$ is well defined iff $kx\equiv jx\pmod{mn}$, iff $mn\mid (k-j)x$. Are we then supposed to just choose $k$ and $j$ which forces $n\mid x$?

Comment: Scratch what I said about Ext-groups in now deleted comments. That was just wrong. You seem to be looking for a commutative diagram with the prescribed short exact sequences at the top and bottom. The game is then to find a matching homomorphism as the center vertical mapping. It will automatically be an isomorphism as long as it is well defined and makes both squares commute! My answer is based on doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at possible substitutes for the isomorphism
$f(1+nm\mathbb{Z})=(1+n\mathbb{Z},1+m\mathbb{Z})$. If, instead, we try
$$f(1+nm\mathbb{Z})=(a+n\mathbb{Z},b+m\mathbb{Z}),$$
then for the left square to commute we need $ma\equiv 1\pmod n$, and for the right square to commute we just need $b\equiv 1\pmod m$.

So here we can select $b=1$, and the remaining question is, when does an integer $a$
exist such that $ma\equiv1\pmod n$. This is how the $\gcd$-condition enters the scene.

Remark: In the comments I suggested using CRT to construct splitting homomorphisms. When you want to produce a commutative diagram with given short exact sequences at the top and bottom, then the goal is to select the appropriate isomorphism in place of $f$. You can't just pick that isomorphism any which way you want, and expect to get a commutative diagram.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I thought the obvious choice would be the right choice, but I guess I was wrong!

Comment: Instead of varying the center vertical mapping, you can also use a different injective homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$. $\overline{1}\mapsto(\overline{m},\overline{0})$ will always make the left square commute, but it is injective only with the gcd-condition in place, so won't be a part of an SES otherwise.